# what's the difference with Dictionary, Object and dynamic?

Tags: actionscript-3

AS3 provide several way to handle something like java Map, but what's the difference with Dictionary, Object and dynamic?

Comment: Have you read the ActionScript documentation at all? Which part did you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Object can be used as a map, where the key is a simple string. An objects purpose though is not solely to work as a map, it just happens, that you can use it as such.

A Dictionary is a key/value map, where the key can be an object, too. This is useful, if you want to find values based on a specific object, that you have. The purpose of a Dictionary really is, to be used as a map.

The 'dynamic' keyword is used to make your own class be extendable in the way, that you can put things into an instance of that class at run-time. Something, which you cannot do, if you do not use the keyword 'dynamic'.

Comment: More precisely, `dynamic`lets you *add properties* to an object instance, that were not declared for the class at compile time.